# Variable may not have been initialized [MISRA 2012 Rule 9.1, mandatory]

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, warnings

I've a function which takes seconds as input and convert it into into time and date. However I'm experiencing warning about Array Variable 'cumDaysInMonths' may not have been initialized [MISRA 2012 Rule 9.1, mandatory]. I've initialized it and then updated in a loop. The warnings are on both lines and linked.

The initialization is as follows:

```
unsigned short cumDaysInMonths[MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR] = {0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334};
```

And the usage within loop is as follows:

```
for(list_index = 2; list_index < MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR; list_index++)
{
    cumDaysInMonths[list_index]++;
}
```

I'm not able to understand the reason of this warning and how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide a full example which shows the actual warning. Both your snippets together are fine if you place them in the right order.

Comment: What is MISRA 2012 Rule 9.1, mandatory?

Comment: This code is far from a [mcve].  Missing is `MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR` and the declaration of `list_index`.  We also have no context as to where, when, or how these two pieces of code are situated in your program.  You could have a global array, and then a local array with the same name (by mistake).  Post a complete program, not two disjointed snippets.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher MISRA is a coding standard. 9.1 wants initialized variables.

Comment: @AreebTariq:  Is this warning given by a static analyser?

Comment: Remove the quantity when defining an array; let the compiler determine the size.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a bug in your static analyser which detects a false positive on both lines you have mentioned.
This is a common problem in static analysis and there is even an IEEE paper on [elimination of such false positives](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7381820).

In the Related questions on the right side, I can see at least one question related to a [MISRA C++ false positive warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206493/misra-c-rule-5-0-3-false-positive-warning?rq=1).